# libudunits2 requires libexpat.so.0, will not accept libexpat.so.1

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04

- Operating System:   Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (Precise)
- Machine:            x86_64, Intel Centrino 2 (2 cores), 4 GB RAM
- Libraries involved: libudunits2.so.0.1.0, libexpat.so.0, libexpat.so.1

Description of problem...

I have built libudunits2.so.0.1.0 on a RedHat 5 machine, along with a program
which uses it. I am attempting to rebuild or run it on Ubuntu 12.04.

The RedHat machine has libexpat.so.0 installed, and that's what libudunits
was built with.

When I attempt to build using udunits2 on my Ubuntu machine,
the build fails, with the explanation that libexpat.so.0 was not found.
The Ubuntu machine has libexpat.so.1 installed.

Attempting to build (or to run the pre-built binary) results in the complaint that libexpat.so.0 could not be found. When linking the executable, we find that it is libudunits2 that wants libexpat.so.0.

I have confirmed that all of the libraries have the right SOnames. ldd and objdump -x haven't revealed any reason that libudunits should not accept libexpat.so.1 instead of
libexpat.so.0, since shared libraries are generally backward-compatible. (see command outputs at the end of the post for more details)

Maybe libexpat has no backward-compatibility between these two versions?

Maybe I've missed something else?

NOTE: the libudunits I am using on Ubuntu 12.04 was copied over from RedHat 5.

COMMAND OUTPUTS...

```
REDHAT 5...
===========
bash$ ldd libudunits2.so | grep expat
        libexpat.so.0 => /lib/libexpat.so.0 (0xf7efc000)

bash$ objdump -x libudunits2.so | grep expat
  NEEDED      libexpat.so.0


UBUNTU 12.04...
===============
bash$ ldd libudunits2.so | grep expat
        libexpat.so.0 => not found

bash$ objdump -x libudunits2.so | grep expat
  NEEDED                libexpat.so.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just been informed by one of my coworkers that a change in major SOnumber reflects an incompatibility between the two versions, while a minor SOnumber does not.

So, if it had been libexpat.so.0.0 and libexpat.so.0.1, there wouldn't have been a problem, but as soon as it goes from libexpat.so.0 to libexpat.so.1, it means there's an incompatibility.